# How to remove list margin?

Tags: html, css

I have a list that contains 3 items. However, it has a little margin on its left side, I want it to disappear.

Here is my code:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I have margin space on my left side</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
<p>
Hi! I am a text without any margin!
</p>
```

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to find out where it is applied (it comes from the browser stylesheet) - and then overwrite it in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set padding of your `ul` to 0. Here's a snippet:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hey, now I don't have extra space on my left side!</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
<p>Hi! I am a text without any margin!</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```css
ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
        
li{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>I have margin space on my left side</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
<p>
    Hi! I am a text without any margin!
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset `ul` `margin` and `padding` to zero (`0`)

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I have margin space on my left side</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
<p>
Hi! I am a text without any margin!
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the `browser default` and you have to `reset` the `padding` for the `ul` element.

If you look at the `chrome dev tool`, you can see the browser defaults as below.

[image]

**Code**

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I have margin space on my left side</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
<p>
Hi! I am a text without any margin!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global style rule, like so:

```
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Use this code on top of your style sheet. It will reset default margin and padding for all elements.

Hope it will work.